# how to get day of week from sqlite date and time string?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I am using sqlite datetime commands to get, set and manipulate my date and time strings.
I first construct the sql command in a const char* and then execute the command using sqlite3_exec while using a call back function to fetch the results if any from the (select from) commands.

```
orderDataBaseRc = sqlite3_exec(orderDataBase, pSQL[i], callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

Now I want to know the day of week (mo-su) and month (jan-dec) from my date and time string.

How do I do that in sqlite? The documentation says something like i can get much wiser from the documentation and examples are hard to find.

Let me give some examples of the sql commands that I am using:

```
"create table orderTable (OrderId integer primary key asc, CustomerId integer, OrderValue, OrderDescription, OrderDateTime DATE, OrderDueDateTime DATE)"

"create trigger insert_orderTable_OrderDate after insert on orderTable begin update orderTable set OrderDateTime = datetime('now') where rowid = new.rowid; end;"

"update orderTable set OrderDueDateTime = datetime('" << iOrderDateTime << "', '+1 day') where OrderId = " << orderId
```

So now I need to be able to know the day of the week and month of my date time string.

According to the suggestion below I have constructed the following statement and fired off with sqlite3_exec:

```
"select strftime('%A', OrderDateTime) FROM orderTable where OrderId = " << orderId;
```

Then in my callback function the following code (azColName[i] seems to come back with a copy of the sql statement:

```
char* columnName;

for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)
{
  columnName = azColName[i];
  string dayOfWeek;

  if(strcmp(columnName, "strftime('%A', OrderDateTime)")==0)
  {
    dayOfWeek = string(argv[i]);
  }
  ...
}
```

But it crashes on

```
dayOfWeek = string(argv[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [strftime()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) with `%w` and `%m`.

Comment: Do I need to encapsulate strftime() in my sql command and how does that look like?

Comment: `"select strftime('%w', OrderDateTime) from orderTable"`

Comment: I have done that, but my program crashes in my callback function.

Comment: I found that sqlite doesn't take %A as defined within strftime to give the full weekday name. So it seems that I have to write my own routine to use %w and convert it to monday-sunday.